# Все возможные операции над двумя целыми числами с помощью оператора CASE

Tags: c++

Помогите написать программу! Заранее спасибо!

Условие такого:
Составить программу, которая бы с помощью оператора CASE реализовала бы все возможные операции над двумя целыми числами.
И если не сложно, поясните, пожалуйста, что к чему. :)

Comment: Нда, хорошо иметь женский ник :) Если бы топикстартёр имел ник типа: @KolyaNikolay его бы заклевали за такой пост - типа *"работа за автора"*, *"учебное задание"* и проч.

Comment: @Barmaley не палите контору, как говорится) Иначе все ленивые школьники будут этим пользоваться)

Comment: @DreamChild: (_шёпотом_) мне кажется, уже пользуются...

Comment: Вообще-то я в самом деле девушка! Учусь в ВУЗе, пока на первом курсе. И мне немного сложно даётся программирование. Неужели так трудно не язвить?
Вот ссылка на меня вконтакте, если уж вас посещают такие идиотские мысли.
http://vk.com/id83159053

Comment: @Mary666 не обижайтесь, лично к вам здесь претензий ни у кого нет. Просто @Barmaley высказал логичную в общем-то мысль, что будь на вашем месте парень, то на него бы обрушился вал критики, а @VladD предположил, что некоторые молодые люди (не имея в виду вас, я думаю) возможно уже прибегают к этой хитрости

Comment: Он высказал может и логичную мысль, но с тонким намёком в мою сторону.

Comment: вряд ли, он хороший, поверьте)

Comment: Да ладно, я не обидчивая. :) Просто не выспалась, мягко говоря. Всё принимаю на свой счёт. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот код, смотрите

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int select, p, m;

  cout << "введите два числа через пробел нажмите клавишу enter: " << endl;
  cin >> p >> m;
  cout << "выберите действие и нажмите клавишу enter: " << endl;
  cout << "1 сложить" << endl;
  cout << "2 вычесть" << endl;
  cout << "3 умножить" << endl;
  cout << "4 разделить" << endl;
  cin >> select;

  switch (select){
    case 1:
      cout << p << " + " << m << " = " << p + m << endl;
      break;
    case 2:
      cout << p << " - " << m << " = " << p - m << endl;
      break;
    case 3:
      cout << p << " * " << m << " = " << p * m << endl;
      break;
    case 4:
      cout << p << " / " << m << " = " << p / m << endl;
      break;
    default:
      cout << "Условие такого: ----> Условие такое :)-" << endl;
      break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @perfect, уверены, что с **int select** будет работать?

Comment: Всё работает. Только заменила русскоязычные слова на латиницу :)
Спасибо Вам огромное :) Есть же добрые люди :)
P.S. По поводу "такого", ну бывает после ночи бодрствования :)

Comment: Пардон, почему-то решил (не посмотрел внимательно код), что предполагается вводить знак операции (т.е. по-человечески -+*/...) из одного символа.

Тогда достаточно изменить тип `select` c `int` на `char`, а `switch` записать так:

     switch (select) {
     case '+':
        ...
     case '-':
        ...
     // и т.д.

Answer (score 5):

В переменной, по которой происходит выбор укажите вид операции (сложение, вычитание, ...):

```
switch ( operation ) {
case addition:
  что делать, если переменная operation имеет значение addition (сложение)
  break;
case subtraction:
  что делать, если переменная operation имеет значение subtraction (вычитание)
  break;
...
default:
 что делать, если эта переменная не имеет ни одного из перечисленных выше значений  
 break;
}
```